# What are these threads ending in "cs0", "gl0", "gdrv0", "shlo0", "disk$0" showing up in some Linux apps?

Tags: linux, user-interface, debugging

I'm writing a graphical application in Rust using [egui](https://github.com/emilk/egui) and when debugging it, I find these extra threads with the following suffixes:

`cs0`
`shlo0`
`gl0`
`gdrv0`
`shlo0`
`disk$0`

Trying to google them lead me to some stack traces where they show up in other graphical applications or frameworks ([gnome software](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/5519), [flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135525)).

What are those threads, what do they do and, most importantly, who's spawning them?

Comment: It is probably your GUI framework. Check that documentation

Comment: Use a debugger to find answers to all of your questions. You can set thread names with https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html#:~:text=The%20thread%20name%20is%20a,the%20name%20of%20the%20thread.